# Android Service Closes After Unbind

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a Service that needs to get some input from an activity. In order for them to communicate I bind the activity to my service and communication works great. However, once the activity is closed and unbound from the service, the service stops too.
Is it possible to unbind without killing the service?

This is how i start the service and bind it:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
//Add user preferences to the service
serviceIntent.putExtra("panel", tbtnBar.isChecked());
serviceIntent.putExtra("sensor", tbtnDown.isChecked());
//Start the service
startService(serviceIntent);

//Bind the service
 isBound= bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection,0);
```

service is unbound in onDestroy:

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        if(isBound)
            unbindService(mConnection);

        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

I've searched around, and all posts just say to start the service before binding it and not use the BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag. Which I seem to be doing.

Comment: "However, once the activity is closed and unbound from the service, the service stops too" -- how are you determining this?

Comment: While its running I have a bright red window pop up that tells me its on. When the service turns off the window disapears.

Comment: Where are you adding and removing the "bright red window pop up" in the service?

Comment: Adding the window in onStartCommand(), removing it in onDestroy()

Comment: I also have the watchdog app running with "Real time CPU" checked to see which services are running. The service stops when the activity is destroyed.

Comment: Okay, from what I have read of the documentation, a service can be destroyed once all clients have unbound from it. In that respect it is working as intended. The better questions is, WHY do you want it to keep running? Is it still doing work that could be needed by the activity once it opens again?

Comment: True, however that only applies to services that are started by the bindService() method, which is why I believe the problem i'm facing lies elsewhere in the code. I'll test it when I have the chance.

Answer (score 1):

Look! This is tricky.
For instance we say that A service can be started either by calling **startService(intent)** or **bindService(intent,serviceConnection,BIND_AUTO_CREATE)**.

When a service is started by bindService then the service's **onStartCommand** is not called after **onCreate**, Actually **onBind** is called instead.

A service which is started by bindService(intent,serviceConnection,BIND_AUTO_CREATE) is destroyed as soon as the activity bounded to it is DESTROYED.

But when we start a service from startService(intent) then the **onStartCommand** is triggered after the **oncreate** and we can return start_sticky from this method.
In this case the service will never be destroyed unless the system do so, irrespective of the service connections binding and unbinding. The service will stay there.